# redraw all dc.js charts with existing filters

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a dc.js view, fairly complex. Which allows users to filter out a set of data, and navigate based on the filters.

Trouble is when the user hits the backbutton, the view reloads the charts, but the applied filters are not shown.

Is there a way for me to redraw the dc.js charts on an existing crossfilter object with the "filter-state" correctly set on the graphs?

Update:

This is a SPA application where I maintain the state in the browser and handle view switching "my self".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find on closer examination that it's a completely new crossfilter object when the page is reloaded. Nothing gets preserved, and although there maybe some tricks to save stuff along with the browser history or use browser local storage, I think you will end up serializing the state in some way.

Here is one really cool example (by my colleague) of using URL rewriting to change the query string to hold the filter state:

http://cscheid.net/static/mlb-hall-of-fame-voting/

It would be nice to abstract this into a library somehow, but I don't know if anyone has done that. The source is available on github:

https://github.com/cscheid/mlb-hall-of-fame-voting

Comment: Interreseting idea with the URL rewriting, I'll have to check that out. I'm not sure it solves the problem though. But if the hall of fame example works then there should be a workaround on my problem as well.

Comment: The html5 history API also allows you to replace/push/pop an arbitrary JSON object along with the URL, a bit more powerful than encoding it all as a query string. But basically the same technique. It's annoying that crossfilter has basically no "getters" so you have to do all the bookkeeping yourself. dc.js does have `chart.filters` though. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#filters-1